# Rewrite urls friendly with htaccess. how I can use it on my site?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm rewriting urls on htaccess using rewrite rules, but when I want that my site uses it I get stuck.
I want my links looks like:

**mysite.com/section/this-is-the-title-of-this-section**

I used rewrite rules to get this:

**mysite.com/section/?id=longalfanum** to **mysite.com/section/longalfanum**

that was cool for a moment. but I checked some few websites for the URLs I realize that they have friendly URL from the beginning
so I changed the url on the  to looks like:

**mysite.com/section/longalfanum-the-title-of-the-section**

now my links doesn't work like before.

my htaccess looks like:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    #this is for avoid extra /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)(/{2,})(.*)$
    RewriteRule . %1/%3 [R=301,L]



    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
    RewriteRule .*/mysite.com/%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

    #this is my rule
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)$
    RewriteRule  /mysite.com/section/$1? [L]
    RewriteRule ^section/(\d+)$ mysite.com/section/?id=$1
```

obviosly this doesn't work. am I missing a step?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
RewriteRule ^section/(\d+)$ mysite.com/section/?id=$1
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^section/(.*)$ mysite.com/section/?id=$1
```

so it matches anything (`.*`) after 'section/', not just digits (`\d+`)

Also, you should add an `[L]` flag to all RewriteRules that don't currently have it to make things a little bit more efficient.

Comment: ok, I changed for (.*) but my url is far to looks like friendly a friendly URL, in the htaccess can I write a rule that gets the title of the section and print it on the URL to make it looks friendly?

Comment: No you can't do that in an .htaccess. You'd have to that in the main server config if you really really wanted to do it in Apache (not an easy task). Otherwise just handle it in you application.

Comment: thanks for respond, if I change  the URL like the way I want in the html  code to looks like: mysite.com/setion/id-title-of(this way doesnt work) can I take the "id" and use it with the htaccess?

I found this service http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ is very useful for this task.

Comment: Yes, the RewriteRule I supplied earlier is written to do just that. I'm not sure where the problem lies ...

Answer (score 0):

my html with php looks like this:

```
<a href="section/?idN=<?= $rowNot[0]['id_new'];?>"></a>
```

in the web browser looks like:

```
mysite.com/section/?idN=alfanum
```

my rule looks like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$
RewriteRule  /mysite.com/section/$1? [L]
RewriteRule ^section/(.*)$ mysite.com/section/?id=$1
```

with this I only get URL like mysite/section/nosensealfanum

it is possible to get the title of new by the htaccess? or I its need to make changes in the way I get the new from the db?

thanks